# Wrong image for Like button with meta properties

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, button, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Even with the meta properties, FB is still fetching the wrong image.

Here is my head:

```
<title>5mm 70L Full Wave LED 5-multi Holiday Lights</title>

<meta name="description" content="5mm 70L Full Wave LED 5-multi Holiday Lights - The LED Warehouse" />

<meta name="keywords" content="5mm,70L,Full,Wave,LED,5-multi,Holiday,Lights" />

<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="index,follow" />

<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />

<meta property="og:title" content="5mm 70L Full Wave LED 5-multi Holiday Lights" />

<meta property="og:type" content="product" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://testing.environmentalled.com/5mm-70L-Full-Wave-LED-5-multi-Holiday-Lights-p105.html"/>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.environmentalled.com/images/products/839.jpg"/>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="The LED Warehouse" />

<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001735835873" />

<link href="/style-led.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/magiczoom.js"></script>
```

I use these meta properties on other non php pages without any issue.

Comment: Check it with [debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

From the og:url you specified: http://testing.environmentalled.com/5mm-70L-Full-Wave-LED-5-multi-Holiday-Lights-p105.html

From that the linter sees:

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="5mm 70L Full Wave LED 5-multi Holiday Lights" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://testing.environmentalled.com/5mm-70L-Full-Wave-LED-5-multi-Holiday-Lights-p105.html" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.environmentalled.com/images/products/839.jpg" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="The LED Warehouse" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:admins" content="100001735835873" />
```

Is this incorrect?

The only thing the linter says is that it cannot find og:description.

Is http://www.environmentalled.com/images/products/839.jpg the correct image you want?

Comment: Yes, thats the image I want, but it doesn't pick it.